# Footer Fixed cant stay centered/justified

Tags: html, css, frontend, footer

So basically the footer is in the bot of the body.

But since I want the footer to always stick at the bottom of screen instead of below all items, I have to set it as position fixed. And it messes up its positioning.

I have to mention that I have bootstrap5 linked but has nothing to do with the prob.

Another question to frontend dev, should I be using this method for footers or go with frameworks ? Like do you guys even use it nowadays ?

```css
html {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   overflow: hidden;
   min-height: 100vh;
   height: 100vh;
}

body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 95%;
   margin: auto;
}

footer {
   text-align: center;
   color: mediumpurple;
   bottom: 5px;
   background-color: rgb(215, 212, 212);
}
```

```html
<body>

    <header>
      …
    </header>

    <div class="container" id="collection">
      …
    </div>

    <footer>

        <small> Lorem, ipsum dolor...</small>

    </footer>
</body>
```

In this case the footer is below all other items {position: fixed;} the left side margin stays (cause of the body's left side margin of 2.5% since the body is 95% of html, but on the right side it keeps going.

Without position fixing:
[image: 0]

With position fixing:
[image: 0]

But if I set the max-width of the footer to 95% it works and It will be the same width as the body, when it should be smaller since it inherits from the body. And it always start with the correct left side margin whether I set width to 50% or 10000%.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the footer should be outside the body tag? cause if that happens the css that you use on the footer some of them will function but most of them won't. All because the footer tag is inside the body tag in which the first one will be applied on the css is the body tag
[footer tag should be outside the body tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQkat.png)

Comment: thank you, I solved problem through complicated css, apparently im using the wrong approach, you just fixed it all lol

Comment: I am glad that I managed to helped you even just a little bit